# Physically based rendering from theory to implementation

Tags: books

Physically based rendering form theory to implementation - http://www.amazon.ca/Physically-Based-Rendering-Theory-Implementation/dp/0123750792/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1425451050&sr=1-1&keywords=physically+based+rendering

has all the information which is in Real time rendering - http://www.amazon.ca/Real-Time-Rendering-Third-Tomas-Akenine-Moller/dp/1568814240/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1425451133&sr=1-1&keywords=real+time+rendering

in terms of rendering?
And techniques listed in Physically based rendering can be executed using HLSL?

Comment: This is not a computer science question, but one about comparing tables of contents of two books.

Answer (score 2):

No, and no.

The framework in PBRT is not geared to real-time rendering on current graphics hardware. The goal of PBRT is to solve [Kajiya's rendering equation](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~leopini/DISCIPLINAS/IA725/ia725-12010/kajiya-SIG86-p143.pdf), and it does this using unbiased Monte Carlo integration. This is very much "non-realtime" at the moment.

The state of the art in realtime physically-based rendering is to render static or semi-static scenes (using a lot of precomputation), or to model only some (common) types of light transport path. There's also work in using GPUs to accelerate unbiased rendering of the full rendering equation, but it's not even close to realtime yet. This is an active research area.

Having said all this, both books are excellent, and well worth reading.